# Xamarin - Loading block map iteraction

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a custom activity indicator experimenting a block on map interaction.

The map and the activity are in a grid and I use a binding property to running or not the map as:

```xml
<ContentPage>
 ...
    <Grid>
    ....
        <local:CustomMap HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        x:Name="MyMap" IsVisible="{Binding InMap}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        IsShowingUser="true" PinClicked="PinClicked"
                        MapType="Street"/>

        <customActivity:CustomActivityIndicator 
                        x:Name="BusyIndicator" 
                        IsRunning= "false"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" />     
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The problem is on the map that has bloking when user interact with it, inclusive if IsRunning is ever false.

Why it could be happen?

Comment: If you remove the `customActivity:CustomActivityIndicator`, map interaction will works well?

Comment: yes, it works removing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CustomActivityIndicator` blocks interaction, because it's first element that you tap/touch.

You have to remove it from your grid for interacting with other view or use some hacks like setting `HeightRequest=0`.

Comment: Tx. Where I use the loading?

Comment: @doxsi I don't understand your question.

Comment: removing from grid, and put ... where?

Comment: @doxsi if you need to cover map by your `CustomActivityIndicator`, I think the best practice is to set `HeightRequest=0` when needed.

Comment: "You have to remove it from your grid " but, where I have to put the my customActivity inside xaml? I have a ContntenPage and inside a Grid with map.

Comment: @doxsi sorry, maybe it's not a word I mean. You "can" remove it from your grid, for example programmatically, that's just an option. You see, I can't understand what exactly you want from your app, because of a few information you provide.